# FindRoot not obtaining solution for nonlinear system of log equations

Tags: equation-solving, numerics, nonlinear

There is a system of 9 non-linear equations, `eq` containing logarithms that I think it should be solvable numerically. There are a total of 9 variables with two of these variables being given and the rest of values are to be found `{pa0, pa1, pa2,pb00, pb01, pb02, pb11, pb12, pb22}` each being between 0 and 1.

```
eq[pa0_, pa1_, pa2_, pb00_, pb01_, pb02_, pb11_, pb12_, pb22_] := {
  pa0 == 1 - pb01 - pb02 - pb11 - 2 pb12 - pb22,
  pa1 == pb01 + pb11 + pb12,
  pa2 == pb02 + pb12 + pb22,
  pb00 == 1 - 2 pb01 - 2 pb02 - pb11 - 2 pb12 - pb22,
  0 == 4.68` + 0.2585199978643553` Log[pb00] - 
    0.2585199978643553` Log[pb22], 
  0 == -2.1599999999999997` + 0.2585199978643553` Log[pb11] - 
    0.2585199978643553` Log[pb22], -8.12` == 
   0.8600000000000001` + 0.08617333262145177` Log[pb00] - 
    0.17234666524290354` Log[pb01] + 
    0.08617333262145177` Log[pb11], -0.64` == 
   1.58` + 0.08617333262145177` Log[pb00] - 
    0.17234666524290354` Log[pb02] + 
    0.08617333262145177` Log[pb22], -2.96` == -0.7` + 
    0.08617333262145177` Log[pb11] - 0.17234666524290354` Log[pb12] + 
    0.08617333262145177` Log[pb22]
  }
```

My failed attempt to obtain solutions for the `{pa0, pa1, pa2, pb00, pb01, pb02, pb11, pb12, pb22}` fixing `pa0=1/3;pa1=1/3` and using  `FindRoot`:

```
FindRoot[
 eq[1/3, 1/3, pb02, pb11, pb12, pb22],
 Flatten[{{pb00, pb01, pb02, pb11, pb12, pb22}, RandomReal[1, 6]}, {2}]]
```

The evaluation of `FindRoot` returns nothing. Am I missing something here? Any help appreciated, thanks!

Comment: You have nine equations, but only six variables.

Comment: yes, I was fixing three of the variables by giving values of 1/3. Please see edited post. If I am correct there should be some redundancy in the 9 equations so we can't solve for all 9 variables from the 9 equations. This is why I fix values for ```pa0```, and ```pa1```

Comment: You can't simply fix the values: you have to reduce the number of equations to equal the number of variables. Your function `eq` makes a list of nine equations regardless of whether its arguments are free variables.

Comment: Thanks. This is helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the nonlinear system of equations doesn't have a real solution

```
eq[pa0_, pa1_, pa2_, pb00_, pb01_, pb02_, pb11_, pb12_, pb22_] := {
pa0 - (1 - pb01 - pb02 - pb11 - 2 pb12 - pb22), 
pa1 - (pb01 + pb11 + pb12), 
pa2 - (pb02 + pb12 + pb22), 
pb00 - (1 - 2 pb01 - 2 pb02 - pb11 - 2 pb12 - pb22), 
4.68` + 0.2585199978643553` Log[pb00] - 0.2585199978643553` Log[pb22],
-2.1599999999999997` + 0.2585199978643553` Log[pb11] - 0.2585199978643553` Log[pb22], 
-8.12` - (0.8600000000000001` + 0.08617333262145177` Log[pb00] - 0.17234666524290354` Log[pb01] + 0.08617333262145177` Log[pb11]), 
-0.64` - (1.58` + 0.08617333262145177` Log[pb00] - 0.17234666524290354` Log[pb02] + 0.08617333262145177` Log[pb22]), 
-2.96` - (-0.7` + 0.08617333262145177` Log[pb11] - 0.17234666524290354` Log[pb12] + 0.08617333262145177` Log[pb22])}

NMinimize[Norm[eq[pa0, pa1, pa2, pb00, pb01, pb02, pb11, pb12, pb22]], {pa0, pa1, pa2, pb00, pb01, pb02, pb11, pb12, pb22}, Method -> "DifferentialEvolution"]
```

Comment: Thanks. This is an interesting approach. I run ```NMinimize[
 Norm[eq[1/3, 1/3, pa2, pb00, pb01, pb02, pb11, pb12, pb22]], {pa0, 
  pa1, pa2, pb00, pb01, pb02, pb11, pb12, pb22}, 
 Method -> "DifferentialEvolution"]``` and I obtain negative values for the solutions. Can the minimisation be somehow constrained within certain range? i.e. ```Thread[0 < {pa2, pb00, pb01, pb02, pb11, pb12, pb22} < 1]```